# What's the optimal way to get the absolute difference between two angles in degrees (AS3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, modulo

I'm working on a 2.5D game engine where characters can move at arbitrary angles, but need to load animations at the closest pre-drawn "rotation" to the angle they're actually moving at. Their actual motion may cheat by some amount each way.
As they change direction randomly, this means each time they rotate we need to search a vector of which "rotations" -- sprite sheets -- are available.

When I rotate the whole camera, this becomes a big problem because we need to compare the desired rotation to the 4, 8, 12 or 16 available rotations for each character, house, etc. with up to 256 on screen at a time. The heaviest code is getting the difference between each known rotation and the one requested. That is to say, if the AI requests a rotation of 346º, we iterate through let's say 12 rotations for this character and see they have a pre-drawn sheet at 330º and one at 0º. The code that is choking is a really simple function to see which one of those two angles is closer to 346º. That sounds silly, but it's true -- because I have to run it on every one of the 12 pre-drawn rotations, on every one of 256 characters, every frame.

Currently, for each known rotation, I check it against the requested one (direction of the character's motion) and see which comparison is closest. This is the function I use to get the difference, and I'm looking for a way to make it faster, because for some reason it's a huge hog, totally disproportionate. Apparently abs and min are quite slow. I know I can use a helper var, but that's not what seems to be slowing it. We CAN assume that degrees passed are already within a range of 0-360, but we can't guess the order they'll come in:

```
public static function AngleDifference(a:Number,b:Number):Number {
        var dif:Number = Math.abs(a-b);
        return (Math.min(dif,360-dif));
    }
```

I'm wondering if it would be faster to somehow wrap this another way, rounding to a preset hash table or even some kind of crazy bit math. It's basically part of a sort function...

Answer (score 2):

Fastest method, at the expense of memory, would be a big two dimensional lookup table. If your input is 25 and 180, you go to position 25 in the first lookup table and then 180 in the second nested lookup table, so return table[25][180]. Total space usage is 360^2 = 129600 elements, about 506 kB for 32 bit integer (I think) or 253 kB for a short int.

Watch out for silent widening and narrowing primitive conversions when mixing shorts and ints.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about the language you are editing with, but if it is anythig like Java, make sure you are using the equivalent of integer primitives and not the full blown Integer object, that would cause a serious, serious slow down.

Comment: It's AS3 and the inbound values are floats. Casting them to int may actually be slower than flooring or rounding them. A giant lookup table seems out of the question... I was thinking of caching frequently used combinations as a last resort, but with 360º rotation that doesn't make much sense either...

Comment: @joshstrike Maybe the fact that they are floats is causing the calculation to take a lot of time. What hardware are you on? Try casting them to an int and see if it saves time overall as integer operations should be much quicker. Also why is a lookup table out of the question? Does the hardware have serious memory constraints?

Comment: @joshstrike Yeah I don't think caching would be a good idea, there is not going to be much temporal locality of reference so there will be a lot of thrashing, it will probably slow it down due to overhead

Comment: it's compiling for android and iphone... (it's amazing this runs at all, but this exact function is soaking up 30-40% of the cpu cycles right now, when fully loaded with characters. That's equal to the cost of rendering all of them!)

Comment: Not all phones have an fpu so floating point operations have to be done in software which equals a major slowdown. Change your program to try and use integers as much as possible, all the way through. See if it helps. I still think a lookup table is your best bet, lookup tables are super fast, you will not get much faster than them.

Comment: hmm. I'm wondering still if there isn't some clever bitmask comparison method I could use... this is the kinda thing I'm going to waste the next 4 days doodling and having weird dreams about probably... =D

Comment: There may be, I don't know. But the problem is you are receiving the values as floats, which do not have such a simple bit representation, unlike an int. Because of that, I highly doubt there is some clever bitmask method you can use without casting to an int first

Comment: I tried casting them to int, and was scratching my head because it was actually slower. As it turns out, Math.abs and Math.min expect floats (the "Number" class in AS3) -- so it was actually re-casting them back. Hah.

Comment: Ah I see, yeah definitely better to do it by hand then

Answer (score 0):

As this was AS3, casting to int made things worse when using the Math.abs and Math.min functions, because they expect Number.

Circumventing those functions turns out to be 20% faster when using floats. To give credit to user305179, after that, making the function expect and return int instead of Number (and pre-casting the inbound arguments using a bitwise <<0, instead of implicitly casting them) yielded an additional 25% improvement in the speed of the function. Using a static helper var adds a little extra speed as well.

Altogether this is about 40-50% faster in the game environment, according to Scout:

```
public static function AngleDifference(a:int,b:int):int {
    __dif = a>b ? a-b : b-a;
    return (__dif<180?__dif:360-__dif);
}
```